# Is setting text/plain instead of application/json for JSON response secure?

Tags: javascript, php, json, content-type

I'm working on a PHP script that returns some public JSON content. This file will be fetched on the client with JS.

My issue is that the server (LiteSpeed shared hosting) doesn't have brotli/gzip compression activated for content type `application/json` out of the box.

As a quick fix, if I instead set content type as `text/plain`, the server uses brotli compression.
An alternative I found was setting `ob_start('ob_gzhandler')` at the start of the script (which worked for `application/json`), however that uses gzip compression which is slightly worse than brotli.

I know this is probably bad practice, but are there any other reasons why this could be bad? Would it be a security issue? What's the point of setting `application/json` anyway?

I found a post stating the importance of content types with regards to security, but it wasn't clear to me if it mattered for my specific use case: [Content-Types Matter More Than You Think](https://textslashplain.com/2018/01/08/content-types-matter-more-than-you-think/)

Comment: What do you mean, "slightly worse"? Do I get it right, that your application is a bleeding edge performance, and using gzip instead of brotli ruins all the experience?

Comment: _"What's the point of setting application/json anyway?"_ - to let the receiver know what type of data they are getting. Your JSON might for example _automatically_ get parsed on the receiving end based on this, whereas if you send it as text/plain, you (or whoever else the receiver is) might need to explicitly trigger that yourself.

Comment: Compression isn't a security feature, so that's not a factor... By using the correct mime type, the client knows how to interpret your response.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Slightly worse as in slightly more bytes. Let's say the difference is 1 kB, hence I'm asking for a good reason to not use text/plain.

Comment: For me it looks like a premature optimization

Comment: @CBroe Well I'm in control here, so I'd parse the response as JSON from the client no matter what.

Comment: @Cerbrus I know the compression itself isn't, but the question is whether it can be abused. Using the correct mime type (application/json) makes my average response 20 kB instead of 5 kB. And it's not a public API.

Comment: What makes you think that this **could** be a security problem? Please add all clarification to your question by editing it, not to the comment section

Comment: @NicoHaase Thanks, I've included a post that talks about the importance of content types with regards to security.

Comment: @dansan That post is more about data security in regard to the example of `application/json`, not necessarily exploitable code execution. What they are referring to is data leakage of non-public information.

Comment: Please add all clarification to the question itself, to make it self-contained. Add the relevant concerns to it, such that reading the linked post is optional

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: **no**, there is no inherent security risk in using `text/plain` over `application/json`.

TL;DR:

Really, the answer comes down to an "agreement" of sorts with your client-base. Ideally, as a provider, you should always strive to adhere to standards and best-practices. In reality, occasional corners need to be cut.

In any case, you, as the provider, need to determine what is best for the consumer. If you have a small number of specific consumers, you could get away with simply relaying a specification (OpenAPI/Swagger, for instance) to your consumer(s) to follow, you should document any quirks or discrepancies between your specification and your actual implementation.

Are you saving that much in time/data by using a different compression? Does that savings outweigh the proper implementation of your API? Will you spend more time/money answering questions about why your API does not behave as described?

It's all situational, but as developers, we should always strive to provide the best implementation of a product (whatever that may mean to all parties involved).

Addendum:
In a situation like yours, if compression was important but relied on a particular content type, I would design it to default to the fastest (`text/plain` in your case), but allow others (by way of the `Accept` header) to designate a different response. Then just document the difference if they choose that option.